# Save function mongoose with ES6

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I wonder if it's possible to do this behaviour in ES6, without an external library. I refer to `.save` function because when trying to do that I got an error and it says "Cannot read property 'saveInfo' of undefined".

```
schema.statics.saveInfo = function(info,callback){

      var toSet = new Info(info);

      // I want this save on es6
      toSet.save(function(err){
         if (err){
           return handleError(err);
         }else{
          callback("Success!...");
        }
      }); }
```

`module.exports = Info = mongoose.model('userInfo',schema);`

and this in es6 is sth like this

```
schema.statics.saveInfo = (info, callback) => {

      const toSet = new Info(info);
      toSet.save(err => {
         if (err){
           return handleError(err);
         }else{
          callback("Success!...");
        }
      });
```

`export default Info = mongoose.model('userInfo',schema);`
but I got an error that says Info is undefined.

Comment: ECMAScript 2015 is backwards compatible, so it seems to me that you tried using a new feature, which did not work. Please be more specific on what exactly doesn't work. Also, that last line is not valid syntax.

Comment: Did you mean to pass your `schema`, not the `Schema`? Also, what is `toSet` and why is `Save` not used?

Comment: Did you get it working in ES5? Please show us that code. Otherwise this has really nothing to do with ES6 - your code doesn't even use any new ES6 feature.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that to use the export default,I  had to create the variable before before being able to export it
So I change my code from this
`export default Info = mongoose.model('userInfo',schema);`

to this:

`const Info = mongoose.model('userInfo',UserSchema);`
`export default Info;`